# Angular 1 Form Validation Errors not Showing

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have a form validation and I cannot seem to let my validation error message show.

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
   <input name="email" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="formdata.email" email-valid required>
   <div class="ng-cloak" ng-show="registration_form.email.$touched">
      <p class="field_error" ng-show="registration_form.email.$error.required">Email is required</p>
      <p class="field_error" ng-show="registration_form.email.$error.emailValid">Email is invalid</p>
      <p class="field_error" ng-show="registration_form.email.$error.minlength">Email is too short</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Part of my Controller:

```
var email = Validators.validateEmail(data.email);
if (email != true) {
    $scope.registration_form.email.$error.emailValid = true;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try this ng-show="registration_form.email.$dirty || registration_form.email.$touched"

Comment: You are not supposed to change it like that. As angular validation runs - it will recalculate $error object and clear your changes. Add custom validator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **custom validator**.
For example bellow, email will be valid only if has length more than 13 (5+ characthers before @) and ends on *.com* or *.net*.
In function `emailValid` you can check whatever you want.

```js
var app = angular.module('FormExample', []);

var EMAIL_REGEXP = /^[a-z0-9](\.?[a-z0-9]){3,}@mail\.(com|ru)$/;
app.directive('customEmail', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$validators.emailValid = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
          // consider empty models to be valid
          return true;
        }

        if (EMAIL_REGEXP.test(viewValue)) {
          // it is valid
          return true;
        }

        // it is invalid
        return false;
      };
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="FormExample">
  <div>
    <form novalidate name="registration_form">
      <label>Email:
                    <input custom-email name="email" type="text" ng-model="email" minlength=14 required>
                </label>
      <div class="ng-cloak" ng-show="registration_form.$submitted || registration_form.email.$touched">
        <p ng-show="registration_form.email.$error.required">Email is required</p>
        <p ng-show="registration_form.email.$error.emailValid">Email is invalid</p>
        <p ng-show="registration_form.email.$error.minlength">Email is too short</p>
      </div>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```